# Managing Visual Studio Projects for a website and custom usercontrols

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have one main project for the cms we are using for our website. I have also created usercontrols to include in the site, but I think I would like to keep these in a separate project and just reference them in the main project. Is this a best practice and how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it's best to group your inter-related web components together as much as possible.

If the user controls in question are going to be unique to each deployment of the CMS or if they are likely to be updated more frequently than the rest of the website then it may be desirable to isolate them to their own project. Failing these cases, placing the controls in a separate project is likely to be more of a hassle than it is worth.

Comment: The usercontrols are updated way more often than the cms and whats more the cms is updated at independant intervals to the custom controls. That is why I was thinking I should look into spinning them to their own project. It is referencing and such that I am not sure how to do.